# How to adjust size of textblock to monospace font and resolution

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I am making a roguelike in WPF. The middle of my window is the map (a textblock where I use a monospace font). So it simulates a console.

This textblock should be 100 characters in width and 50 characters in height, whatever the resolution of the user's screen.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Just define the height and width so the size is static?

Comment: Or if this for whatever reason does not fit your need make a grid put two textblocks in one with your console content and a secund one with 100 characters and 5 lines set its visibility to hidden and bind the consols height and width to it. A little hack but will do the trick without any converter